# What kind of algorithm would solve this problem: shortest routing between 3D cubes

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms, computational-geometry

I have these in 3D space:

1. Green points where blue routes begin
2. Black hole/sphere where all blue routes end ⚫
3. Red cubes that must not have any collision with blue routes
4. Blue routes beginning from green points, ending at black hole, and avoiding red cubes

[image: Schematics]

I intend to:

- Compute the *shortest* total blue routes. The objective is the *minimum* total blue routes.
- Assume the red cubes are triangle meshes in 3D space.
- Share segments between the routes as much as possible. Since any share is counted only once.

I wonder what family of mathematical algorithms I'm looking for. It should be optimization. But I need more details to actually implement it. It would be great too if some repositories on GitHub are introduced. Any programming language is fine.

Comment: In your example, the blue routes do not intersect each other.  Is that an additional requirement?

Comment: @RobPratt In three dimensions, it's not really relevant whether routes can intersect... detours around any intersection points can be added with an arbitrarily small extra cost.  I think the real question is whether two green points can *share* part of their routes to the goal, with a shared segment's length being counted only once.  (The question doesn't say so.  But if they can't, then we just want the optimal route from each green point independent of all the others.)

Comment: @RobPratt The routes could intersect with each other. That's OK.

Comment: @mjqxxxx The routes can share segments. A shared segment length is counted only once. That's right.

Comment: It sounds similar to finding "obstacle-avoiding Steiner trees".  e.g. [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48518-X_17) article defines the problem as: 

Given: A set $Z$ of $n$ terminals inside a simple polygon $\omega_0$ with a set $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\ldots, \omega_h\}$ of $h$ separated polygonal obstacles (holes).

Find: The shortest (with respect to the $L_2$-metric) network $T$ in $\omega_0$ spanning $Z$, and avoiding obstacles in $\Omega$.

Comment: The author's note that this is NP-hard in general.  Unfortunately the full paper is behind a paywall. This is a 2D formulation of the problem, but perhaps the methods involved can be generalized.

Comment: @JairTaylor Right,  I don't have access to the paper. My problem is a 3D one, but it might be possible to generalize from 2D to 3D.